# CSS with nested disabled elements

Tags: javascript, html, css

A project I am involved in, I noticed that disabled items don't look disabled enough. I planned to easily fix this with a little CSS.

Normally, I simply would play with the opacity to get it to look right. Anything with the disabled attribute would get a partial opacity.

```
[disabled] {
    opacity:0.3;
}
```

However, our code has several nested elements that have the attribute disabled. Something like this:

```
<div disabled="disabled">
    <p disabled="disabled">
        <input data-val="true" type="checkbox" value="true" disabled="disabled">
        </input>
    </p>
</div>
```

That is a simplified example. Some of these are disabled several more levels deep!

What results with the CSS I propose is the opacity get applied several times so it is .3*.3*.3=.027. This makes some elements almost disappear while others look too dark, depending on their "nestedness".

There are several conflicting reasons the code might disable items and that is partly why there is so much disabled-nesting. So removing all the extra attributes will be lots of work, not in the schedule. I don't think any fancy CSS pseudo-selectors can describe this but I may be wrong.  Can we somehow only make the outermost or innermost disabled element apply the opacity? I tried using [disabled]:last-child (or first-child) but that didn't seem to do it.

CSS would be best but Javascript or Jquery would be possible too.

Here is a screen showing the result with nested opacity:
[image: nested disabled styling]

Comment: I'm not 100% certain, but I feel like the `disabled` attribute is not really designed for elements like `div` and `p`. http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/disabled-elements.html

Comment: Can you add a new class to the parent element only? In that case you just need to set the opacity of this new class.

Comment: Can you post a complete code example in your question that replicates the issue?

Comment: I think it is probably true that the disabled attribute is not really designed for elements like div and p. However, this is our legacy code at the moment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to restore opacity on nested `disabled` elements as follows:

```
.disabled {
    opacity:0.3;
}
.disabled .disabled {
    opacity:1;
}
```

See this working **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v5uda6cq/)** sample.

**EDIT:**

Same idea using `[disabled]`. See **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v5uda6cq/1/)**

```
[disabled] {
    opacity:0.3;
}
[disabled] [disabled] {
    opacity:1;
}
```

Comment: `[disabled]` not `.disabled`

Comment: @Quantastical, same idea applies for `[disabled]`. See edit.

Comment: Right, I just didn't want to confuse future visitors with the notion that a disabled attribute could be selected with a class selector. Thanks for the update.

Answer (score 0):

```
selector{
opacity: x;
}
```

opacity is inherited property, so you have to set back opacity to 1, for all child elements, or at least for next child like so:

```
[disabled] {
opacity: 0.3;
}
[disabled] > *:not([disabled]){
opacity: 1;
}
```